# Confusion regarding sheaf cohomology and singular cohomolgy

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, algebraic-curves, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective curve (in particular irreducible) of genus $g$ at least $1$. We know that $H^1_{\mbox{sing}}(X,\mathbb{Z})=2g$. But, since $X$ is irreducible, the locally constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ is flasque, hence the sheaf cohomology $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$. My confusion lies in the fact that $X$ is locally contractible and it seems that the two cohomologies must coincide in this case. I do not understand, where I am going wrong. Can someone help!

Comment: The singular cohomology seems to refer to the classical topology of $X$ (as a complex manifold), whereas irreducibility refers to the Zariski topology.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, singular cohomology with classical topology and irreducibility with Zariski topology.

Comment: If you want to get the singular cohomology from algebraic geometry, you can use étale cohomology where you have Artin comparaison theorem. There is also the algebraic de Rham cohomology (defined as the hypercohomology of the de Rham complex).